# AvAudioUnitEffect as Chorus

Tags: objective-c, audiounit, avaudioengine, audioeffect

I cannot find any indication how to build a Chorus EFX in AVAudioEngine.
I can see AvAudioUnitReverb and so on, but I cannot find any indication
ho to create a Chorus.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in AVAudioUnitEffect nodes are limited to [reverb](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiounitreverb), [delay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiounitdelay), [distortion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiounitdistortion), compressor and [EQ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiouniteq). There might be a couple that I missed but chorus isn't one of them.

List of effects:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiouniteffect

Comment: I cannot find it in that link

Comment: That's what I meant, I don't think it's included.